# Contract.methods.transfer is a not a function error using web3

Tags: web3js, web3j, web3js-v1.x

Running something simple as this:

```
Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(this.contractABI, this.contractAddress)
Contract.methods.transfer(toAccount.address, transfferAmount).encodeABI()
```

Gives me following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: _this.tokenContract.methods.transfer is not a function
```

What could I be doing wrong? I have showed the Contract variable on the console, and it in fact does not have "transfer" in its methods property.

Comment: check you abi. Do you see a transfer function in you abi?

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh Thank you for your help. I just checked and no, I do not see a transfer function in my ABI. The ABI that I am using is actually some random ABI that I found on the internet, because I thought all ERC-20 token's ABI's are the same. Are they not? The custom token I am trying to transfer is this: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xb1ef691806fbccc3b84f46186827ef883c33bcce 
If not all ABI's are the same, where can I find the ABI for my token?

Comment: You can not call transfer method if that does not exist in ABI. You need to get the ABI of the contract, which has transfer method.. ;-)

Comment: @Yogesh-EtherAuthority.io Thank you for stopping by to help me. How can I get the ABI of the contract? I could not find it on etherscan.

Comment: If your code is verified, then you will see that in etherscan.. or if you are using your remix, you will find it in compile section. If you use truffle, you will find that in build folder

Comment: @Yogesh-EtherAuthority.io Thank you so much. One last question. How does your contract get verified? What does it mean for your contract to be verified?

Comment: Thank. Verifying is done by Etherscan: https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2  and as you can see in that page, you need to give all those contract information and then it will be verified.. and you will unlocked many other features

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using web3 v0.x then you can send transaction by following:

```
// creation of contract object
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
// initiate contract for an address
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);
// send a transaction to a function
myContractInstance.myStateChangingMethod('someParam1', {value: xxx, gas: xxxx});
```

If you are using web3 v1.x then you can send transaction by following:

```
var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
myContractInstance.transfer('some params')
   .send({
           from: account address, 
           gas: 0x00, 
           gasPrice: 0x00
        }).then(receipt=> {consol.log(receipt)});
```

Comment: What is meant to be put in 'some params' ?

Comment: ERC20 tokens have a `transfer` function signature that accept two input parameters `to` and `value`. see https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Contract-ERC20-ABI

Answer (score 0):

Why are we still dealing with answers to a problem that is still occuring but the answer is four years and four months old.  Unfortunately the error is still occuring so there is a flaw some where.  As there error I am receiving doesn't make sense.  I am getting TestContract.methods.name().call() is not a function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).